# ¿Como recuperar último pull-request de master desde github a mi computadora?

Tags: git, github

Estoy utilizando git desde github Desktop. Termine de hacer mis cambios en el branch que tenía y lo uní al master, pero seleccione un branch anterior y el máster volvió a mis ficheros anteriores (De hace un mes). Quise volver al master/origin que acabo de hacer pull-request pero me da este error[image: Error que me muestra github desktop]

No se que hice mal. Me ha estado costando un poco esto de git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Encontré la solución.**

Era más sencillo de lo que parecía. Desde gitHub desktop retorne al último branch que hice, no se había eliminado. Y recupere todos los ficheros. Cree un nuevo branch a partir de este último y elimine el anterior. Ahora ya funciona todo correctamente. El error que me mostraba era porque había commits pendientes. Los descarte y puesto que no los necesitaba y pude hacer todos los movimientos descritos.

Por si a alguien le sucede lo mismo. Es importante que en gitHub desktop no haya commits pendientes pues a diferencia de usar la terminal no es necesario el comando add, aqui se hace automáticamente.